# Gaussian Integral and Inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, integral-inequality, gaussian-integral

We are required to calculate $\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-x^2}dx$ in three steps:

1) Show $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}, 1-t\le e^{-t}$ and $1+t \le e^t$ (This is easily proven; no need to elaborate on this)

2)Show $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \int^{\sqrt{n}}_{0}(1-\frac{x^2}{n})^{n}dx\le\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-x^2}dx\le\int^{\infty}_{0}\big(1+\frac{x^2}{n}\big)^{-n}dx$

Comment: This is where I start having problems. my initial thought was to look at $\big(1-\frac{x^{2}}{n}\big)^{n}$ and we know $\big(1-\frac{x^2}{n}\big)^n\to e^{-x^2}$ and $\big(1-\frac{x^2}{n}\big)^{n}$ is monotone increasing which means $\big(1-\frac{x^2}{n}\big)^n \le e^{-x^2} \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is this correct and I'm not certain on the second inequality.

3)Finally, we should use $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \int^{\sqrt{n}}_{0}\big(1-\frac{x^2}{n}\big)^ndx\leq\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-x^2}dx\le \int^{\infty}_{0}\big(1+\frac{x^2}{n}\big)^{-n}dx$ as well as the substitutions $x=\sqrt{n}\sin t$ (I presume for the first integral) and $x=\sqrt{n}\tan t$ (I presume for the third integral whereby $ t\in \big[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\big]$. I am struggling to integrate the first and third integral because both still have terms in $n$. How can I do this?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

2. You can use the first question with $t=\frac{x^2}{n}$:
   $$\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n} \right) \leq e^\frac{-x^2}{n} \leq \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n} \right)}$$
   so taking the power $n$:
   $$\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n} \right)^n \leq \left(e^\frac{-x^2}{n}\right)^n=e^{-x^2} \leq \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n} \right)}^n=\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n} \right)^{-n}$$
3. For the first integral you obtain:
   $$ \sqrt{n} \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos(t)^{2n+1} dt$$
   this is a [Wallis' integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals) and this is known that  $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos(t)^{k} dt \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2k}}$ so:
   $$\sqrt{n} \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos(t)^{2n+1} dt \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2 \times 2}}$$

For the second one you obtain:
$$\sqrt{n}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \left(\frac{1}{\cos^2(t)}\right)^{-n}  \frac{1}{\cos^2(t)}dt=\sqrt{n}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos(t)^{2n-2} dt$$
and again from the equivalent of Wallis' integrals you obtain:
$$\sqrt{n}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos(t)^{2n-2} dt \sim \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$